# Could not open input file: symfony

Tags: windows-10, symfony-3.1

Environment: Windows 10, WAMP.
I'm trying to install symfony 3 and to have opportunity to execut it globally. I want just to type in cmd in any directory

```
php symfony new new_project
```

I made all rules according to documentation http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup.html

But I always take the error: "Could not open input file: symfony"

I made symfony.bat and write there

```
@echo off & php "symfony" %*
```

I moved the files symfony and symfony.bat to thew directory which is in environment variable Path.

Nothing helped me!

Does anyone has suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

It is better to use composer.
get it from [here](https://getcomposer.org/)
and install symfony by this:

```
composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition my_project_name
```

for more information see [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup.html).

Comment: Thx! ) With composer it works fine, I know. But I want to understand, why it's not working with script directly as mentioned in official documentation.